# Fixing the alignment on a neural network diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, neuralnetwork

I am working on some simple neural network diagrams, but am having some trouble getting the alignment to work. Can anyone help me with figuring out how to get the alignment to work correctly for the hidden and output nodes. I am just not sure how to work with the offsets in diagrams like these.

Here is the picture and the code follows.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, headinclude, footinclude]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, positioning, decorations.markings,
  arrows.meta, calc, fit}
\def\layersep{3.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, node distance=\layersep]
    \tikzstyle{every pin edge}=[<-,shorten <=1pt]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt]
    \tikzstyle{input neuron}=[neuron, fill=red!50];
    \tikzstyle{output neuron}=[neuron, fill=orange!50];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron, fill=green!50];
    \tikzstyle{annot} = [text width=4em, text centered]

    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {$x_{\y}$};

    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=0.5cm]
            node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};

    % Draw the output layer node
    \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O) {};

    % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
            \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);

    % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);

    % Annotate the layers
    \node[annot,above of=H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot,left of=hl] {Input layer};
    \node[annot,right of=hl] {Output layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, provide a MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/231952

Comment: @Ivan I am a little confused since I provided the code above. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: A minimal working example is a single, full, self-contained source code, complete with preamble and with all the packages needed to get the output, which can simply be copied and typeset

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, I just added that. I added the header and the tikz packages, etc.

Comment: the only offset is in the line here -- `\path[yshift=0.5cm] node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};`  -- you can experiment with the value of `yshift`

Comment: @krishnab  please have a look at the answer below -- `layersep` was not defined in your code -- positioning code syntax is wrong -- correct is `right=of.....` and not `right of =........`  -- the correct style definition is also added

Comment: @jsbibra Oh thank so much. Okay, I added the `layersep` variable. Sorry, I just forgot to include that. I will also make note of the positioning syntax. Thanks so much for you help and improving this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,shapes.multipart, positioning, decorations.markings,arrows.meta, calc, fit}
\def\layersep{2.5cm}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        shorten >=1pt,->,draw=black!50, 
        node distance=\layersep,
        every pin edge/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt},
        neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=25pt,inner sep=0pt},
        input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
        output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=orange!50},
        hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
        annot/.style ={text width=4em, text centered}
        ]
        % Draw the input layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,4}
        % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
        \node[input neuron] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {$x_{\y}$};
        
        % Draw the hidden layer nodes
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
        \path[yshift=-0.5cm]
        node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};
%       
%       % Draw the output layer node
        \node[output neuron,pin={[pin edge={->}]right:Output}, right of=H-2] (O) {};
%       
%       % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
%       % hidden layer.
        \foreach \source in {1,...,4}
        \foreach \dest in {1,...,3}
        \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);
%       
%       % Connect every node in the hidden layer with the output layer
        \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
        \path (H-\source) edge (O);
%       
%       % Annotate the layers
        \node[annot,above=1cm of H-1, node distance=1cm] (hl) {Hidden layer};
        \node[annot,left=1cm of hl] {Input layer};
        \node[annot,right=1cm of hl] {Output layer};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```