# Centering TikZ Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

Is there a simple way to align the following two sets of the bipartite graph horizontally, i.e. move the three nodes on the left 1.5 times the vertical node distance downwards?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[grow right sep=2cm,empty nodes,nodes={fill,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=2mm}] {
    subgraph K_nm [n=3,m=6]
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: you need to use matrix for that -- this is the natural placement for such graphs-- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/588629/197451

Comment: - please see the answer below if it suits the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of the `chains` library, nodes on grid, defined lenght for calculating neurons distances.

Minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass[border=3.141692]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}
\newlength\ND
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = \ND, on grid,
  start chain = going below,
neuron/.style = {circle,draw, fill, minimum size=5pt, inner sep=0pt,
                 on chain, node contents={}},
                        ]
\setlength\ND{8mm}    % Nuuron Distance
% left neurons
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \node (n1\i) [neuron];
% right neurons
    \node (n21) [neuron, above right=1.5\ND and 4*\ND of n11];
\foreach \i in {2,...,6}
    \node (n2\i) [neuron];
% Connect every input newrons with every output one
\foreach \i in {1,...,3}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,6}
    \draw (n1\i) -- (n2\j);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,shapes,shapes.multipart, positioning, decorations.markings,arrows.meta, calc, fit}
\def\layersep{4cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=\layersep,
    neuron/.style={circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt},
    input neuron/.style={neuron, fill=red!50},
    output neuron/.style={neuron, fill=orange!50},
    hidden neuron/.style={neuron, fill=green!50},
    ]
    % Draw the input layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,3}
    % This is the same as writing \foreach \name / \y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4}
    \node[input neuron] (I-\name) at (0,-\y) {};
    
    % Draw the hidden layer nodes
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,6}
    \path[yshift=1cm]
    node[hidden neuron] (H-\name) at (\layersep,-\y cm) {};    
    %       % Connect every node in the input layer with every node in the
    %       % hidden layer.
    \foreach \source in {1,...,3}
    \foreach \dest in {1,...,6}
    \path (I-\source) edge (H-\dest);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Though, it seems there's no easier way with an option, right?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way using `layered layout`:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{layered}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph[empty nodes,
    layered layout, % <- new
    level distance=2cm, % <- new
    grow=right, % <- new
    nodes={fill,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=2mm}]
    {subgraph K_nm [n=3,m=6]};
\end{document}
```

[image: produces]

In this case you don't need to calculate anything, that work is left to `layered`.

Here is minimal example where you can compare its usage:

```
\tikz \graph[layered layout,grow=right] {a -- {b,c}};
\tikz \graph {a -- {b,c}};
```

[image: minimal example comparation]

Comment: Great, thank you!